# how to convert a String in to a 2d array (java)(GameBoard)

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, char

I have a String text which represents a level in the game Sokoban. 
I have a few different characters which each has a different meaning.

- '#'  = a wall
- '$' = the player
- '@' = the baggage to move
- '.' = the target the baggage has to drop in to

I'm using a 2d array (10x10)

this is the level for example:

```
String level = "##########" + "#       .#" + "#      ###" + "#  @  ####"  
             + "#   $ ####" + "#     ####"
             + "##########" + "##########" + "##########" + "##########";
```

now I'm wondering how I can convert that String into the 2d array so that the first # will be at [0][0] and so on...

I've tried this so far but unfortunately, I don't think I'm even close to the solution.

```
    int SPACE = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < level.length(); i++) {
            char s = level.charAt(i);
            for (int rij = 0; rij < SPACE; rij++) {
                for (int kolom = 0; kolom < SPACE; kolom++) {
                    switch (s) {
                    case '#':
                        spelbord[rij][kolom] = "#";
                        break;
                    case '@':
                        spelbord[rij][kolom] = "@";
                        break;
                    case '$':
                        spelbord[rij][kolom] = "$";
                        break;
                    case '.':
                        spelbord[rij][kolom] = ".";
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand your String level statement.  Is that the actual format, because all of those strings of different lengths will concatenate into one long String.

Comment: the actual format is each 10 char long but the editor didn't include spaces here but if there is for example # ## it should actually be ########## so each section is 10 chars long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your String level is just a String of 100 characters with "#", "@", " ", "$", and ".". Each character maps to a distinct element in the board which is a char[][] matrix.

Currently, your code loops through the String. At every iteration, you iterate through the board (wrongly). This is unnecessary since you should already know where to put the char into the board.

To fix this, keep a separate counter for the String and iterate through the board once. Every time you place a char into the board, you increment the counter.

```
int counter = 0;
for (int rij = 0; rij < SPACE; rij++) {
    for (int kolom = 0; kolom < SPACE; kolom ++) { //you are supposed to increment kolom here, not rij
        spelbord[rij][kolom] = level.charAt(counter++); //increment counter after assignment
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, declare `spelbord` as a char array (`char[][]`). It is a lot more efficient and easy to deal with. By the looks if it, you don't need it to contain strings.

Then just write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < level.length(); i++) {
    spelbord[i / SPACE][i % SPACE] = level.charAt(i);
}
```

If you get a null pointer exception, you have probably forgotten to initialise spelbord. Make sure you allocate an array for it.